# Finding top 5% in Excel

Tags: excel, list, sum

I have a list of data in Excel, with values attributed to the different samples. I would like to subset the top 5% from all my data. How can I do this in Excel?

```
 sample  value
 a       0.6001437980
 b       0.0983224370
 c       0.0493093160
 d       0.0427906350
 e       0.0413478790
 f       0.0299204810
 g       0.0259600660
 h       0.0215505810
 i       0.0167398000
 j       0.0131496290
 k       0.0105364240
 l       0.0082647980
 m       0.0068507060
 n       0.0065234580
 o       0.0050233730
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cell C2, enter

```
=B2>=PERCENTILE($B$2:$B$63,0.95)
```

you can then copy this to C3:C63.
Column C now shows TRUE only for those rows with a B value in the top 5%.

Additionally you may like to apply a filter.

Comment: Its returning an error within the formula? Not working.. And I have 62 values in total. I accounted for those, and tried with only first 16 and still did not pass.

Comment: Please provide the exact error specifics. What language are you working with? you could just paste some formula that is working so i can see.

Answer (score 1):

You can specifie rang of your data and then color it with very little effort.

[Here is an example, where you can color top N records:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X7iilzQfgP8)

Hope it helps :)